# Google play store app installation history

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

What would cause the Google history to show certain apps installed, but then uninstalled, all at the same exact time or within one minute of each other?

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: Maybe the apps were updated during those times.

Comment: So are you saying that when apps are updated, they automatically uninstall and reinstall? Is that certain?

Comment: It's my theory yes. Even on a PC most apps (programs) when they are updated, the old version must be removed in order to install the new. To be 100% sure, update in the near future an app and check if their activities will be reflected as uninstalled and installed as shown on the images you posted

Comment: Did you test? What were the results?